# How efficient is list.index(value, start, end)?

Tags: python, list, indexof

Today I realized that python's `list.index` can also take an optional `start` (and even `end`) parameter.

I was wondering whether or not this is efficiently implemented and which of these two is better:

```
pattern = "qwertyuytresdftyuioknn"
words_list = ['queen', 'quoin']
for word in words_list:
    i = 1
    for character in word:
        try:
            i += pattern[i:].index(character)
        except ValueError:
            break
        else:
            yield word
```

or

```
pattern = "qwertyuytresdftyuioknn"
words_list = ['queen', 'quoin']
for word in words_list:
    i = 1
    for character in word:
        try:
            i = pattern.index(character, i)
        except ValueError:
            break
        else:
            yield word
```

So basically `i += pattern[i:].index(character)` vs `i = pattern.index(character, i)`.

Searching for this on *generic_search_machine* returns nothing helpful, except a lot of beginner tutorials trying to teach me what a list is.

**Background:**
This code tries to find all words from `words_list` which match `pattern`. `pattern` is a list of characters a user entered by swiping over the keyboard, like on most modern mobile device's keyboards.

In the actual implementation there is the additional requirement that the returned word should be longer than 5 characters and the first and last character have to exactly match. These lines are omitted here for brevity, since they are trivial to implement.

Comment: Just running a basic test on my machine with a longer random pattern, the second method, using `index()` with a `start` parameter, is about 5 orders of magnitude faster. It's usually safe to trust the built-in underlying C implementations when speed is required, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What Charles said. The 1st way is primarily slower because it has to construct a new `pattern[i:]` string object on every loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This calls a built-in function implemented in C:

```
i = pattern.index(character, i)
```

Even without looking at the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Objects/listobject.c#l2147), you can always assume that the underlying implementation is smart enough to implement that efficiently, i.e. that it does not look at the first `i` values in the list.

As a rule of thumb, using a built-in functionality is *always* faster than (or at least as fast as) the best thing you can implement yourself.

**The attempt to make it better:**

```
i += pattern[i:].index(character)
```

This is deffinitely worse. It makes a **copy of** `pattern[i:]` and then looks for `character` in it.

So, in the worst case, if you have a `pattern` of 1 GB and `i=1`, this copies 1 GB of data in memory in attempt to skip the first element (which whould have been skipped anyway).